# How to interpret (read) signed 24bits data from 32bits

Tags: python

I have raw file containing signed 24bits data packed into 32bits
example:

```
00 4D 4A FF 
00 FF FF FF
```

I would like read those data and get signed integer between [-2^23 and 2^23-1]

for now I write

```
  int32_1 = file1.read(4)
  val1 = (( unpack('=l', int32_1)[0] & 0xFFFFFF00)>>8
```

but how to take the 2-complement into account to interpret `00FFFFFF` as -1 ?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Are your numbers big-endian, i.e., does `00 4D 4A FF` have the decimal value of 5065471?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and little endian. I'm working on windows 10 64bits

Comment: Ah, ok. So `00 4D 4A FF` should be -46515. FWIW, this is really easy in Python 3: `int.from_bytes(b[1:], 'little', signed=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can shift 8 bits to the left, take the result as a signed 32bit integer (use ctypes library), and divide by 256

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> i = 0x00ffffff
>>> i
16777215
>>> i<<8
4294967040
>>> ctypes.c_int32(i<<8).value
-256
>>> ctypes.c_int32(i<<8).value//256
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is making things more complicated than they need to be. However, you really should specify the endian type correctly in the `unpack` format string.

```
from binascii import hexlify
from struct import unpack

data = ('\x00\x03\x02\x01', '\x00\x4D\x4A\xFF', '\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF')

for b in data:
    i = unpack('<l', b)[0] >> 8
    print hexlify(b), i
```

**output**

```
00030201 66051
004d4aff -46515
00ffffff -1
```

---

FWIW, here's a version that works in Python 3 or Python 2; the output is slightly different in Python 3, since normal strings in Python 3 are Unicode; byte strings are "special".

```
from __future__ import print_function
from binascii import hexlify
from struct import unpack

data = (b'\x00\x03\x02\x01', b'\x00\x4D\x4A\xFF', b'\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF')

for b in data:
    i = unpack('<l', b)[0] >> 8
    print(hexlify(b), i)
```

**Python 3 output**

```
b'00030201' 66051
b'004d4aff' -46515
b'00ffffff' -1
```

And here's a version that only runs on Python 3:

```
from binascii import hexlify

data = (b'\x00\x03\x02\x01', b'\x00\x4D\x4A\xFF', b'\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF')

for b in data:
    i = int.from_bytes(b[1:], 'little', signed=True)
    print(hexlify(b), i)
```